# Usage of "under the sound of one's voice"

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

I'd encountered the following excerpt from a speech by Martin Luther King (there's a [video](https://youtu.be/CrvYyGHUSoE?t=6), if you're interested):

> "I want to say to everybody **under the sound of my voice** this afternoon
> that you are somebody."

I'd also encountered a similar usage by Malcolm X (that's too an excerpt from a speech, quoted by Maya Angelou in [The Heart of a Woman](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=1zt-bI44dv4C&pg=PA179)):

> "Every person **under the sound of my voice** is a soldier"

There are only few Google results to this kind of usage.

My question is:
Does it have a certain origin, or is it just a rhetorical phrasing?
Also, is this kind of structure (i.e., "under the x of y") is used elsewhere?

Comment: _Under the spell of his or her x_ is very common (x could be voice, charm, beauty, etc.), although one usually wouldn't use this phrase when speaking of oneself, as it would sound quite vain.

Comment: Nor sure about the answer to your question, but I think the phrase means "everyone who is hearing what I have to say here today."